# How to give random numbers to an array elements in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program which sums negative and positive elements of array in a function. But I am having problem in giving random numbers to array. What can I do?

MY CODE=>

```
 def meto_foo(a):
        t1=0
        t2=0
        if a<0:
            t1=t1+a
        if a>0:
            t2=t2+a
        return t1,t2        


    nums = []

    for i in range(5):
        nums = random.randint(-5,5)
        print(nums)

print(meto_foo(nums))
```

MY OUTPUT =>

```
3
-3
0
-1
2
(0, 2)
```

Comment: [Edit] this question and clarify what you want to do because "sums negative and positive elements of array in a function" isn't very obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the for loop, you're re-assigning the list variable `nums` to a single random integer value.  You can append to the list instead.

```
nums = []

for i in range(5):
    num = random.randint(-5,5)
    nums.append(num)

print(nums)
```

Answer (score 1):

> But I am having problem in giving random numbers to array. What can I
>   do?

Use list comprehension to generate the random number array

```
num = [random.randint(-5,5) for i in range(5)]
```

Comment: Can the downvoter please explain the reason? Would help me improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just modified your code: Run It

```
def meto_foo(a):
    t1=0
    t2=0
    for i in a:
       if i<0:
          t1=t1+i
       if i>0:
          t2=t2+i
    return t1,t2 

nums = []

for i in range(5):
   num = random.randint(-5,5)
   nums.append(num)
print(nums)
print(meta_foo(nums))
```

Mistake in your code is you are just sending only last value to the meta_foo() method

Answer (score 0):

If all you are looking for is a list of positive an negative numbers and sum them, then you don't really need `random` as `range` should give you list like that and you can use `sum()` to add all the values:

```
nums = [i for i in range(-5,5)]
print(nums)
#Output:
[-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
print(sum(nums))
#Output:
-5
```

However, if you want to restrict in range 5, then use `random()` to generate values in that range and `sum()`:

```
import random
nums = [random.randint(-5,5) for i in range(5)]
#[0, -3, 2, 2, -5]
sum(nums)
#Output:
-8
```